Download file from TeamCity with SSO using bash
I need to download an artefact from TC using a bash command (it should work in Ubuntu 22.04.3 deb based server). TeamCity authentication mode is SSO only via MS account and 2FA authentication. Is it possible somehow to wget my TC builds?
I tried
wget --user my_username --ask-password -v --load-cookies 2sso.cookie --save-cookies auth2.cookie --keep-session-cookies https://teamcity***.iso

but got
Resolving teamcity***.com (teamcity***.com)... 1.2.3.4
Connecting to teamcity***.com (teamcity***.com)|1.2.3.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401

Username/Password Authentication Failed.

In this command, user is my MS account.

Why is your command refering to https://teamcity***.iso, but in the output you see teamcity***.com?

https://teamcity***.iso is the full path including an ISO name (file name) I want to download, teamcity***.com is the hostname

You are using --ask-password. How did you supply the password? Interactively? Are you sure that you typed the correct password?

First access token needs to be crated in your Team City user profile. Then curl might be used to download artifacts.
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <bearer token here>" <Team City file link> > ~/<file name to save>

